# Отображение cardview в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Есть 3 класса:

1. Класс - определяющий фрагмент
2. Класс - `RecyclerAdapter`
3. Класс - `MainActivity`

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы отобразить н-ое количество `cards` в `RecyclerView`. Почитал офф документацию http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/lists-cards.html, но все равно не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так.

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textView = (TextView) textView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        }

    }


    public RecycleAdapter(String[] mDataset){
        this.mDataset = mDataset;
    }

    public RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int Viewtype) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.examplefragment, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class exampleFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.examplefragment;
    private View view;


    public static exampleFragment getInstance() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        exampleFragment fragment = new exampleFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment ;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT,container,false);

        return view;
    }

}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.layout;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecycleAdapter recycleAdapter;
    private String[] mDataset;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(LAYOUT);
         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(mDataset);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        initDrawerLayout();
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        FloatingActionButton fab  = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floating);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Let's do it", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EnterActivity.class);
               // startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        initTabs();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) нужно возвращать кол-во объектов в методе

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```

2) заменить тип `String[]` на `ArrayList<String>`

3) И естественно dataSet не должен быть пустым, не нашел добавления элементов у Вас в коде